# batch with for loops in one for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, networking, cmd, mapping

Im trying to search in user folders for a file witch needed to be deleted. I dont know the exact name of the folders on each machine in the network, but i know it is from h0000001 to h0003000. So Im trying to look on every machine if a specific folder exist and delete a file in it.
I tryed this:

```
 @echo off
    set user=username
    cls
    set userpass=password
    cls
    
    echo.
    
    for %%f in (992 993 995) DO (
    net use A: \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
    
    for /l %%j in (1,1,9) DO (
    if not exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j" goto notexistj
    if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file" del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file"
    :notexistj
    )
    
    for /l %%d in (10,1,99) DO (
    if not exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d" goto notexistd
    if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d\Desktop\file" del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d\Desktop\file"
    :notexistd
    )
    
    for /l %%s in (100,1,999) DO (
    if not exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h0000%%s" goto notexists
    if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h0000%%s\Desktop\file" del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h0000%%s\Desktop\file"
    :notexists
    )
    
    for /l %%h in (1000,1,3000) DO (
    if not exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000%%h" goto notexisth
    if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000%%h\Desktop\file" del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000%%h\Desktop\file"
    :notexisth
    )
    
    xcopy "%cd%\for_copy\*" "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\Public\Desktop" /Y
    net use /delete A:
    )
```

Can anyone help me, what am I doing wrong?

This code worked fine for my needs:

```
@echo off
set user=username
cls
set userpass=password
cls
    
echo.

for %%f in (992 993 995) DO (
    
for /l %%j in (1,1,9) DO (
net use A: \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
if exist \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file del \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file
net use /delete A: /Y
)
    
for /l %%d in (10,1,99) DO (
net use A: \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
if exist \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d\Desktop\file del \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d\Desktop\file
net use /delete A: /Y
)
    
for /l %%s in (100,1,999) DO (
net use A: \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
if exist \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h0000%%s\Desktop\file del \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h0000%%s\Desktop\file
net use /delete A: /Y
)
    
for /l %%h in (1000,1,3000) DO (
net use A: \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
if exist \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000%%h\Desktop\file del \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000%%h\Desktop\file
net use /delete A: /Y
)

net use A: \\FH0%%f01.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
xcopy "%cd%\for_copy\*" "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\Public\Desktop" /Y
net use /delete A: /Y
)
```

Comment: There is no need to check a directory for existence which you check a file for existance in, because the latter cannot exist without the former anyway, hence `if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file" del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file"` is enough; moreover, you could just try to delete the file by `del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h000000%%j\Desktop\file"`, because you won't succeed in case it doesn't exist anyway; append _space_ + `2> nul` to avoid error messages (though this would suppress messages about insufficient access as well)…

Comment: Hi, I tried this,
`net use A: \\compname.domain\C$ /u:domain\%user% %userpass%
if exist "\\compname.domain\C$\Users\username\Desktop\file" del "\\compname.domain\C$\Users\username\Desktop\file"
net use /delete A:`

 but nothing happens.
Im getting the message "The system cannot find the path specified. 
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to A:.

I made also a log file to see if the path is ok, it is everithing fine. I can access the specified path with mapping thru my local file explorer.

Comment: You map a drive `A:` but you are not using it – why? after mapping `A:`, `del "A:\Users\username\Desktop\file"` should do it; (note that you missed an opening `"` in `if exist`). Not sure but I think the order of parameters for `net use` could be relevant (type `net help use`)…

Answer (score 0):

Labels are not allowed within a code block.

Since you are seeking an `and` function, use (eg)

```
if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d" if exist "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d\Desktop\file" del "\\FH0%%f01.domain\C$\Users\h00000%%d\Desktop\file"
```

which obviates the need for your attempted-jumps.